# Integrate Microsoft Dynamics NAV with third party app

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I built web app by golang, and I want integrate it with Microsoft Dynamics NAV, and I don't know from where can start,

Is there a way to integrate Microsoft Dynamics NAV by REST API, or any other methods?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of NAV we're talking about, a number of its object types (not really OO; think ~modules) can be published as SOAP or OData webservices. For reading and writing NAV data, I would probably recommend a page-based webservice.

For more information on how to expose a NAV page as a webservice, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355316(v=nav.90).aspx (SOAP) or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh166960(v=nav.90).aspx (OData).

Answer (score 0):

You can Integrate your third Party apps with dynamics Nav by using OData Link
Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2016 and greater versions support these features
To Get OData Base URL you have to run dynamics nav Administration Shell as an admin
Click on OData Services here you can Get Odata Port and URL
IF your OData Service is not Enable than click the check box and restart the Dynamics Nav Instance